# Problem with python threding and kivy add_widget method

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

Here is my a simple code, which uses Python socket and threading. Here the thread cannot able to run a function of adding widget List dynamically.

Note: The thread is able to successful run all function except the function for add_widget.

Thanks in Advance.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField, MDTextFieldRound
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDIconButton,MDRectangleFlatButton
import sys
import socket
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, IRightBody
import threading
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import mainthread

kv="""

ScreenManager
    LoginPage:
    MsgPlatform:

<LoginPage>:
    name:'login'
     
    MDTextField:
        id:ip
        hint_text:'Enter ip-Addresh'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.7}
        size_hint_x:0.3
        
    MDTextField:
        id:port
        hint_text:'Enter port'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        size_hint_x:0.3
    
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text:'Join'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_release:
            root.login()
            root.manager.transition.direction='left'
            root.manager.transition.duration= 0.2
            root.manager.current='msgplatform'
  
            
<MsgPlatform>:
    name:'msgplatform'
    
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id:container
    
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id:cont        
    
    MDIconButton:
        icon:'send.jpg'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.95,'center_y':0.05}
        size_hint:0.04,0.03
        on_release:
            root.send_msg()
            root.clear_msg()
                    
"""

s=socket.socket()
data=''


class recvThread(object):
   
    def __init__(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recv, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()    
        
    def recv(self):
        while True:
            global data
            data=str(s.recv(5000),'utf-8')     
            if str(data)!='':
                MsgPlatform().recvMsg()
             
class LoginPage(Screen):
    def login(self):     
        host=str(self.ids.ip.text)
        port=int(self.ids.port.text)
        
        s.connect((host,port))
      
class MsgPlatform(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        recvThread()
        
    def recvMsg(self):
        
        cont=self.ids.container
        global data 
        print(data)
        c=cont.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=str(data)))                
    
sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginPage(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(MsgPlatform(name="msgplatform"))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        script=Builder.load_string(kv)
        return script
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is Thread:

```
class recvThread(object):
   
    def __init__(self):
        
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recv, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()    
        
    def recv(self):
        while True:
            global data
            data=str(s.recv(5000),'utf-8')     
            if str(data)!='':
                MsgPlatform().recvMsg()
```

Here is the thread implementation function.

```
def recvMsg(self):
        cont=self.ids.container
        global data 
        print(data)
        c=cont.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=str(data)))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is exactly your issue?

Comment: Methods that modify the GUI display must be run on the main thread. Try writing a tiny method that just does the `add_widget()` of the `OneLineListItem`. Then call that method using `Clock.schedule_once()` to get it done back on the main thread.

Comment: It still not worked, the ListItem still not added